# Existence of Higgs Mechanism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higgs

Given a gauge group G and a subgroup H, does it always exist a Higgs Mechanism breaking G down to H? Is it unique, or with an obvious classification?

Comment: Just thinking out loud. You have to have a representation $\rho: G \rightarrow End(V)$ in which the Higgs multiplet lives, and a vector $v \in V$ (the ground state) for which the part of the group $G$ which leaves $v$ invariant (also sometimes called *the little group*) is equal to $H$. Generally, it might turn out to be $H/Z$ for some finite group $Z$ (e.g. when $SU(5)$ is broken to the standard model, $Z = Z_6$). In this case you have to prove that discrete transformations from $Z$ leave all your particle content invariant.

Comment: at the classical level, there may be topological obstructions against reduction of the structure group of a principal bundle to (closed) subgroups

Comment: I would expect some classification to exist, at least for simple and semisimple G.

Answer (score 2):

The Higgs field starts out transforming in a representation $V$ of $G$. When acquiring a VEV that spontaneously breaks the symmetry down to $H$, the VEV has to be invariant under $H$, so when we decompose the representation $V$ into representations $\oplus_i V_i$ of $H$, at least one of the $V_i$ needs to be the trivial (or singlet) representation of $H$. A priori there is no guarantee that any given $V$ will contain such a singlet, but there's not much reason to not expect it, either. It depends both in the groups $G$ and $H$ and on the chosen representation $V$ for the Higgs, and we are a priori free to pick *any* representation we want, although most models have the Higgs in the fundamental or adjoint of $G$.

Without further information, we really cannot say much. Once you have fixed the groups $G$ and $H$ as well as the Higgs representation, we can examine the specific choices for their viability.